# How to view HTTP trans-actions when querying web services through MATLAB?

Tags: web-services, debugging, http, matlab, soap

I am using MATLAB and SOAP to query web-services. Aside from using a low-level packet sniffer like WireShark, is the any way to view the outgoing and incoming HTTP packets to debug the interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TCPMon](http://technonstop.com/tcpmon-tutorial): it can stand between the client and the server, showing everything that goes between them.

(It creates a proxy-like "tunnel", listening in one port and forwarding, while showing, everything to another.)